# Help in completing Stack Overflow Careers profile

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Since I failed in certain subjects I haven't completed my degree even after completion of the term of the course.I would like to know how to complete the entry **Degree or Speciality** as given in the image.

[image: Career Profile]

Comment: You  could always mention "...Working on Bachelors of Science in Computer Science"...Or tag it with [Pending] or something that states you have not fully obtained it.

Comment: @JonH:I thought I had to complete my degree to fill this entry.Now there's a sigh of relief.

Comment: There is no js validation to filter out words like pending, etc.  It's just a textbox - have at it.

Comment: I did this by adding `[in progress]` to the end of my "degree or specialty" information. Pick a starting year if you want, but leave the completion year blank.

Answer (score -1):

There are no struct *business* rules and/or validations defined for how you enter those fields.

As stated by [JonH](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318707/help-in-completing-stack-overflow-careers-profile#comment320015_318707) and [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318707/help-in-completing-stack-overflow-careers-profile#comment320021_318707) you can invent your own resolution to indicate when you started and what the current status is.

So adding [Pending] or [in progress] to the degree or specialty textbox is an option. You can leave the end date of the timeframe empty in that case.